# Function to match array of char to a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I am trying to implement a function to compare between a 5 letters string and an array of char and to match them by comparing every char of the string to every char of the array
when I try to use it, it always returns something like `[C@bebf1eb`

Here's my function:

```
static String matching(String myWord1, char[] word_taken) {

    char result[] = new char[5];
    int k = 0;
    char[] myWord = myWord1.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < myWord.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < word_taken.length; j++) {

            if (myWord[i] == word_taken[j]) {

                result[k] = myWord[i];
                k++;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    return result.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when I try to use it, it always returns something like [C@bebf1eb

Yes the `toString()` method for arrays is not overidden so you get the [default implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

Use the String [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29) that takes a char array instead.

```
return new String(result);
```

---

If you want to avoid to recopy the content of the array when creating your String, you could use a `StringBuilder` and append the char to it when it's needed.

At the end, simply return `myStringBuilder.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have also face the same problem and get the correct result by creating a string object

```
return new String(result);
```